# Access Denied in attempt to Create Project in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

According to [the AWS CodeBuild documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-permissions-reference.html), the Create Project operation requires only the `codebuild:CreateProject` and `iam:PassRole` Actions to be granted. I have done this in my role's policy, and set the Resource to `"*"`, but when I click on the `Create Project` button, I immediately get `Access Denied` with no further information. I have no problems doing the analogous operation in CodeArtifact, CodePipeline, and CodeCommit. If I set `"s3:*"`, I do not get the error, so evidently it's an S3 permission I'm missing, but which one?

**What I am trying to do** is create a role with reduced permissions so that a user can run a build and manage CodeSuite resources (add and edit repositories, pipelines, etc.) without using Administrator privileges.

Here is my policy JSON:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*Object",
                "s3:*ObjectVersion",
                "s3:*BucketAcl",
                "s3:*BucketLocation",
                "iam:*",
                "codepipeline:*",
                "codeartifact:*",
                "codecommit:*",
                "codebuild:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

(I am aware this configuration is inadvisable; I am trying to isolate the issue, and provide a minimum reproducible example)

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of educated trial and error, I narrowed it down to a `List*` Action, which is sufficiently specific for my purposes. I'm guessing it's `ListObjects` and `ListObjectVersions`, but I'm too lazy to confirm it.